# Does the sqlite3 CLI ".restore" command delete the existing data in the target database or merge into the existing database?

Tags: sqlite

Use case: I have a background job on one computer ("source"), which is an ETL job of sorts. It updates an SQLite DB file periodically. Then, I periodically want to sync this DB file to a few other computers ("remote"). On the other computers, this database is only read from, not written to.

I would like to sync the DB file to the remote in such a way that a process reading from it on the remote won't read corrupted data while the DB file is being synced. On the source, I use `sqlite3 "$source_db" ".backup ${backup_db}"` to create the backup to sync to the remote. Once the backup has been synced to the remote at path `${remote_db_backup}`, I would like to restore it to the file at `${remote_db}`, which may be being queried by other SQLite processes on the same computer. It looks like the easiest way to do that is to run `sqlite3 "${remote_db}" ".restore ${remote_db_backup}"`.

However, I can't find documentation on what exactly `.restore` actually *does*. On [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), I see `.restore ?DB? FILE       Restore content of DB (default "main") from FILE`. Does the `.restore` command remove the existing content of `${remote_db}` and replace it with the content from `${remote_db_backup}`? Or, does it add new rows from `${remote_db_backup}` but leave existing rows in `${remote_db}`, even if rows with the same primary ID no longer exist in `${remote_db_backup}`?

I'm looking for removing existing content and replacing it with content from `${remote_db_backup}`.